# В Unity Hub не работает кнопка New во вкладке Projects

Tags: unity3d, unity-hub

В Unity Hub не работает кнопка New во вкладке Projects. хочу создать проект нажимаю на New кнопку и ничего не происходит. Помогите пожалуйста с этим.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Ваш ХАб не видит установленные версии Unity. Перейдите на вкладку "Installs" и либо установите нужную версию, либо укажите ("Locate") установленную вне ХАБа версию Unity.